# Can't acceed to a derivated class method

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance, virtual

I have this code:

```
struct A {
    void f();
};
struct B: A {
    void f(int i) { std::cout << "f(" << i << ")" << std::endl; }
};
int main()
{
    A* pa;
    pa = new B;
    pa->B::f(5);
}
```

and i get the following error:

> 'B' is not a base of 'A'

Why do i get this error? 
Maybe it is because i can't use a scope which is inside the pointer type (class A)(?).
 And, why if i delete B:: i get the following error?:

> No matching function for call to A::f(int)

This is because i can't call a method which is not defined in my class A through an A type pointer? but this pointer is pointing a B object so... i don't understand this, i'm so initiate with C++ :(

Sorry for my English and thanks to everyone

Comment: Move: "void f(int i) { std::cout << "f(" << i << ")" << std::endl; }" from B to A.  Move "void f();" from A to B.  Make a B pointer "B* pa;".  Change the arrow statement to:  " pa->A::f(5);"  And then compile it and run it.  Think about what just happened and see that you are trying to make the logic essentially work backwards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all the compiler knows, `pa` points to an instance of `A`, or some class other than `B` derived from `A`. It doesn't magically trace the provenance of every pointer to determine that `pa` actually happens to point to `B` at the moment.

You can tell it with a cast though: `static_cast<B*>(pa)->f(5);`

---

On a somewhat related note, your program leaks memory.

Comment: Got it! Thank you, and yes, my program leaks memory, i just wanted to do a short example of that error, i got it in a bigger program but thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in C++.
Specify the **Class** possible only on **Class** from which current **Class** derived like in the following example:

```
struct A {
    void f(int i) {}
};
struct B: A {
    void f(int i) { std::cout << "f(" << i << ")" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    B* pa;
    pa = new B;
    pa->A::f(5);
}
```

Or you should make the following:

```
struct A {
    void f(int i) {}
    virtual ~A() {}
};
struct B: A {
    void f(int i) { std::cout << "f(" << i << ")" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A* pa;
    pa = new B;
    B* pb = dynamic_cast<B*>(pa);
    if (pb) {
      pa->f(5);
    }
}
```

If you want polymorphic behavior it is possible to do something like this:

```
struct A {
    virtual void f(int i) {}
};
struct B: A {
    virtual void f(int i) { std::cout << "f(" << i << ")" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A* pa;
    pa = new B;
    pa->f(5);
}
```

Comment: Note that the first example would call `A::f`, not `B::f`

Comment: op's A's f is different

Comment: And the second example doesn't compile at all: `A` is not polymorphic, `dynamic_cast` cannot be applied to it.

Comment: Both these examples explicitly call `A::f`, but I believe the OP wants to call `B::f`.

Comment: Well, now it compiles, but still calls `A::f`. It's not clear what purpose the `dynamic_cast` dance is supposed to serve.

Answer (score 0):

```
A.f();
```

and

```
B.f(int i);
```

are totally different methods because they dont match the signature (note the int i parameter)

so you can not cast to call a method that doesnt exist...